# Facing unexpected 'misaligned pointer dereference: address must be a multiple of 0x8 but is 0x__' error

Tags: pointers, rust

I am trying to use a library `users` [[Docs.rs](https://docs.rs/users/latest/users/)] [[GitHub](https://github.com/ogham/rust-users)].

When I use try to get the details of user number 5 (i.e. 'operators') on macOS, using the following code...

```rust
use users::get_group_by_gid;

fn main() {
    let group = get_group_by_gid(5).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", group.name());
}
```

...I get an unexpected error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'misaligned pointer dereference: address must be a multiple of 0x8 but is 0x14400880b', /Users/dhruvkb/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/users-0.11.0/src/base.rs:297:34
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
thread 'main' panicked at 'panic in a function that cannot unwind', library/core/src/panicking.rs:126:5
stack backtrace:
   0:        0x104fe684c - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::libunwind::trace::h0a647ce7e8dc2fab
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:93:5
   1:        0x104fe684c - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::hea920694a2a8ac80
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66:5
   2:        0x104fe684c - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt::h7b4e20c1da2ebb61
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:65:5
   3:        0x104fe684c - <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::h819e9cbdf1a9e730
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:44:22
   4:        0x104ff80e0 - core::fmt::write::ha5e9bf3131ecb7c0
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:1254:17
   5:        0x104fe46b0 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::h414ce9994bf17404
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1698:15
   6:        0x104fe6660 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::h28d98f2094da6d1d
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:47:5
   7:        0x104fe6660 - std::sys_common::backtrace::print::h8072db0bbd5bcc3d
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:34:9
   8:        0x104fe7b80 - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::h2c85c5b0c2ede151
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:269:22
   9:        0x104fe7940 - std::panicking::default_hook::hcf2f70992d02f6fe
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:288:9
  10:        0x104fe8058 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::h023af7f90b47eb8b
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:691:13
  11:        0x104fe7f4c - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::h14283519edc1d634
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:580:13
  12:        0x104fe6c6c - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::hc366c0b0cef5b747
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:150:18
  13:        0x104fe7d20 - rust_begin_unwind
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:578:5
  14:        0x104fff6b8 - core::panicking::panic_nounwind_fmt::h48fca0782e5a5b33
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/core/src/panicking.rs:96:14
  15:        0x104fff734 - core::panicking::panic_nounwind::hc8dbc36c10163a33
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/core/src/panicking.rs:126:5
  16:        0x104fff82c - core::panicking::panic_cannot_unwind::h8bbe98643cda7e5c
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/core/src/panicking.rs:188:5
  17:        0x104fca054 - users::base::members::h897f0606a81fa18e
                               at /Users/dhruvkb/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/users-0.11.0/src/base.rs:291:1
  18:        0x104fc9bb0 - users::base::os::unix::GroupExtras::from_struct::hdb1f84273e3fef19
                               at /Users/dhruvkb/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/users-0.11.0/src/base.rs:1060:33
  19:        0x104fc9e44 - users::base::struct_to_group::h968dc5b5260e3ea2
                               at /Users/dhruvkb/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/users-0.11.0/src/base.rs:280:19
  20:        0x104fca3bc - users::base::get_group_by_gid::hbcac997dd823548f
                               at /Users/dhruvkb/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/users-0.11.0/src/base.rs:473:26
  21:        0x104fc875c - ug::main::h9b6b146ea9ce450b
                               at /Users/dhruvkb/Developer/personal/test/ug/src/main.rs:4:17
  22:        0x104fc8908 - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h7e6c46cf308f75b9
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
  23:        0x104fc8874 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h1d5bc4a1fd871dea
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:134:18
  24:        0x104fc89ac - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::hd278346b68dd1f23
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/rt.rs:166:18
  25:        0x104fe2408 - core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once::h6f7eb9f266759f90
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:287:13
  26:        0x104fe2408 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h54b2febb9ea02379
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:485:40
  27:        0x104fe2408 - std::panicking::try::h95a2f9f45aeb75ea
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:449:19
  28:        0x104fe2408 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h9686256fa0fc97a1
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  29:        0x104fe2408 - std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}::h227e8b10bc4e486b
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
  30:        0x104fe2408 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h414d500a3ee5fa44
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:485:40
  31:        0x104fe2408 - std::panicking::try::h4f025820961f1c3f
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:449:19
  32:        0x104fe2408 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h0b71dfe3538d125d
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  33:        0x104fe2408 - std::rt::lang_start_internal::h8ee16b8f6c950a26
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20
  34:        0x104fc8978 - std::rt::lang_start::hb3f96d07eed31802
                               at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/rt.rs:165:17
  35:        0x104fc8854 - _main
thread caused non-unwinding panic. aborting.
[1]    12348 abort      cargo run
```

This error is unexpected because it works for other group IDs like 0 i.e. 'root' or 20 i.e. 'staff'.

This happened in my app so I made a greenfield project with no other dependencies except `users` and it happened there as well. I know that `exa`, a popular CLI app uses this lib, so I cloned its repo and added the same lines from my `main()` to `exa`'s `main()` function.

It works there, which is even more confusing.

[image: Code added to exa's main function]

[image: exa prints "operator", meaning that it works]

Comment: It seems `exa` is using Rust 1.63.0 (because of rust-toolchain.toml) and you're using latest stable for your project.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman you are right! This works on Rust version 1.63.0 (but unfortunately my other dependencies, like Clap, will not support it). Is there a way to get it to work on stable?

Comment: Rust 1.70, implements by default runtime debug assertions for dereferencing misaligned pointers (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/98112). I can confirm that this update has broken some code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some pointer in the list `group.gr_mem` returned by `getgrgid_r()` from libc is underaligned. This may be a bug in the C library, or in the documentation, but likely not in the Rust library because I found nothing in the documentation about this. This causes UB, which mean the compiler can do whatever it wants. Previously, the "whatever it wants" was pretty much ignoring it (minus applying optimizations that exploit this fact). As of latest Rust version (1.70.0) the compiler started being helpful by checking for underaligned pointers in debug builds to help prevent UB. This caused your code to crash. You can silence this checks, if you want. This won't solve you the actual problem of UB, but will at least not crash your program, and you can hope the compiler won't apply any optimization that will suddenly break your code in hard-to-aniticipate ways.

Silencing this check is done by disabling debug assertions. In your Cargo.toml:

```ini
[profile.dev]
debug-assertions = false
```

This is not a good idea. This is not even a bad idea. This is a terrible idea. This disables all debug assertions, even unrelated ones, and just silences the UB without actually solving it. But this may be the best you can get.

A better option is to patch the dependency to avoid the UB. [Patch the `users` dependency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#the-patch-section) and replace the code at `src/base.rs` lines 291-306 (the whole `members()` function) from:

```rust
unsafe fn members(groups: *mut *mut c_char) -> Vec<OsString> {
    let mut members = Vec::new();

    for i in 0.. {
        let username = groups.offset(i);

        if username.is_null() || (*username).is_null() {
            break;
        }
        else {
            members.push(from_raw_buf(*username));
        }
    }

    members
}
```

To:

```rust
unsafe fn members(groups: *mut *mut c_char) -> Vec<OsString> {
    let mut members = Vec::new();

    for i in 0.. {
        let username = groups.offset(i);

        if username.is_null() || username.read_unaligned().is_null() {
            break;
        }
        else {
            members.push(from_raw_buf(username.read_unaligned()));
        }
    }

    members
}
```

You may want to send a PR, but I have no idea if this is a bug in the OS or in the documentation so I have no idea if this should be fixed in the Rust library.